# add a connected user in the list of followers Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a facilitator defined like this:

```
{"_id" : "alyssa", "_class" : "entities.profil.FacilitatorEntity","type" : "facilitator","cwsessionsAnime" : [{"$ref" : "cwsession",$id" : "1L"}],
    "profilFollowEntity":[{"$ref" : "profil","$id" : "sissa"}, 
                          {"$ref" : "profil","$id" : "milou"}]}
```

and when I click a follow button I will have the id of the user connected added to the profilFollowEntitiy list 
[image]
I defined `ng-click="follow()"` and in the controller I declared the method

```
$scope.follow= function(){
    $scope.selectedFac.profilFollowEntity.push({$ref: profil, $id:$scope.user.username});
}
```

and I have declared a service before `profilService.getUser($scope);` to get the username of the connected user that I will add to the profilFollowEntity list. The `methode .follow()` doesn't work, can any one help me please, How could I do that, and thank you in advance

Comment: can you give a quick jsfiddle link to show your problem? I'm guessing there must be a slight mistake for which follow in not working.

Comment: @S the problem is that I have an authentication system I don't know if I could simulate that in jsfiddle

Comment: you are assigning profil to $ref. from where this profil is coming from? don't you think it will be like $scope.profil or something similar?

Comment: @SK $ref:profil: refers to another collection, can because when a profil is connected and go to the facilitator page, he can click follow button to follow this facilitator and so that his name will be assigned in the list of facilitator (whish is profilFollowEntity) . please can you add me to skype, I will show you what I'm doing now, I'm blocked (please, my skype is milou.a and thanks in advance)